# Db file and transaction log segregation in SAN

Tags: sql-server, san

I understand that if we are using HDD then it will be advisable to store the data file and transaction log on different drives (which point to different disks).

However, if the server is using SAN, then whether it's still advisable to put them in different drives?

I have checked with our infra team, our SAN is using flash cards (there are 16 drives in a storage pool where we create logical volumes which is distributed to connected servers).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Seperate volumes for tempdb, data, and backups on SQL Servers in VMs](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/162248/seperate-volumes-for-tempdb-data-and-backups-on-sql-servers-in-vms)

Comment: @mustaccio yes, it does help. According to the post, for two reasons having different drives is good, I.e. disk space safety and future proof. But still, I am not sure if there is performance improvement by having different drives?

Answer (score -1):

One of the worst disaster that arrived to a SQL Server ferm of servers was the lost of all databases, replicates databases and backups for a great company in Germany... Only 60% of the lost data was recovered...

**Why ?**

Because all the storage was done in the same SAN storage ferm, with the same disks and the same hardware...

**What happened ?**

A new firmware that was supposed to correct a bug, had a pervy effect some days after, destroying the all organisation of the storage !

**So, what must I do ?**

- First split the differents file on different storages
- Second, have different hardware and different type of disks,
- third never stores backups in the same warehouse than database files...